# Implicit Flow of OpenID Connect without browser and webview

Tags: openid-connect

If I don't use browser and webview, I can't open page for user authentication, so can native applications not be able to OpenID Connect?

The native application isn't an application that runs on a browser (such as Javascript) or webView.

If it can realize, I would like to know the method.

Comment: Do you mean a mobile app? You can take a look at recommended way of how to implement OAuth2 there https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-oauth-native-apps-12

Comment: With some providers, you should be able to log in using generic http requests by posting a user's username and password, after which you would receive a token (depending what flow you use).

Comment: @Panda
That means I can rialize Implicit flow without a browser and web view?

Comment: I believe so, just mimic the browser flow

Comment: @Panda
What does it mean to "mimic the browser flow"? Please give me a concrete example.

Comment: http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#ImplicitFlowSteps